# How do I display a tree view of different object types in xaml?

Tags: vb.net, xaml

I've been thrown in the deep end on a project with VB.NET and WPF/XAML.  I have a background in C#, so the VB is not a problem.  I have no experience of XAML, and I find the Binding really confusing.
I'm sure it all makes sense once you understand it, but I'm not getting it at all.

I have been given a hierarchical data structure and I need to display it as a tree-like structure.  The nodes at each level of the tree are of different types, so how do I bind and display it?

The data structure I have is like this.  I've simplified it and removed all the Get/Set stuff for clarity.

```
Public Class ComponentProperties
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Double
    Public Property OldValue As Double
    Public Property UpdateValue As Boolean
End Class

Public Class Component
    Public Property Name As String
    *<other attributes>*
End Class

Public Class Design
    Public Property Name As String
    *<other attributes>*
End Class

Public listOfChanges Dictionary(Of Design, Dictionary(Of Component, List(Of ComponentProperties)))
```

I need to display this in a format similar to this:

```
Design Name
    Component Name
        "Changed Component Properties:"
        Name       Value       Old Value     [x]
        Name       Value       Old Value     [x]
        Name       Value       Old Value     [x]
        Name       Value       Old Value     [x]
```

Where there is a row for each ComponentProperty and the [x] represents a checkbox that maps to the Boolean UpdateValue property.
This is where I have got so far with the XAML, but I'm at a loss to work out how to show the ComponentProperties data that I need to display:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding listOfChanges}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
      <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource Main_Light}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key.Name.Value}"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

This displays a treeview as expected, which looks something like this:

```
[MyDesign]
    [Widget1]
        []
    [Widget2]
        []
    [Widget3]
        []
```

I'm not even sure why I'm getting the empty nodes [] below the Component Name.
Apart from that, the structure looks correct.  How do I Bind and display the list of ComponentProperties for each Component?
The nested dictionary/dictionary/list structure has been imposed upon me.  It may not be the best way of doing it, but it's what I have to work with.

Added:
I think I need to have a HierarchicalDataTemplate for each type of node in the tree.  I tried writing 3 different HierarchicalDataTemplates and putting them in the TreeView.Resources section so that the TreeView can choose the right template for each node type.  Each HierarchicalDataTemplate has an attribute something like this:

```
DataType="{x:Type local:Design_Class}"
```

However, I still can't get that to display anything useful.  I think it's probably down to my lack of understanding of ItemsSource and Binding required for the structure I have described.